# Why and how does ASPxTextBox perseveres text across page refresh/reload?

Tags: devexpress

I have noticed funny behavior in ASPxTextBox (and other editors) component. If I have a form with let's say ASPxTextBox and something is written in thta text box, this text perseveres across page refresh. Click on a button refresh or F5. If one does full reload with CTRL+F5 then the value is cleared as it should be on normal reload/refresh.
I know that dev express editors do not use view state, so how do they persist this values.
It would be normal as a user would expect that on refresh values in forms would be cleared. How can one achieve this values to be cleared? And no, I don't have in mind clearing it in code back. Is there a "natural" way?
The behaviour is evident on simplest of cases:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>        
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="ASPxTextBox1" runat="server" Width="170px">
        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can clear it with Javascript.

ASPxTextBox1.SetText("");

Answer (score 0):

> I know that dev express editors do not use view state

DevExpress controls definitely use viewstate. I think when you're pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> it's doing a postback for some reason and the value is being reinstated from the view state. There is no other possible way the control can get the previous value other than from viewstate. I suggest you can verify by putting a breakpoint in `Page_Load` event and checking the value of `Request.Form[control.UniqueID]`. If you get any value then its viewstate in play for sure.